# A word for a memoir written by someone else?

Tags: single-word-requests

Biography is to autobiography as _____ is to memoir?

Is there a single word for a memoir that has been ghostwritten by someone else?

Comment: Sounds like you are under the impression that a biography is ghostwritten.  Are you?

Comment: What did a dictionary or thesaurus suggest? What is special about a memoir? It's kinda like a history that the author is involved in. So to be accurate it seems the right analogy would be 'history'. BUt that's just playing with words.

Comment: If its your memoirs according to someone else, then would it be *rumours* or *hearsay*?

Comment: A memoir is just a type of autobiography, so if someone else wrote it, it's still a biography.

Comment: Biography's are usually ghostwritten, yes, but that's only because they are usually about people who have passed away and are now ghosts, but not always is that the case @area 51

Answer (score 1):

A ghostwritten memoir is a ghostwritten memoir. Although a ghostwriter produces the actual book, it is (hopefully) a faithful reproduction of the subject's memories as told to the ghostwriter. See http://mirandamarquit.com/ghostwrite-memoir/ for a take on the process.

Answer (score 1):

The three examples on my shelf have formed the title from the material gathered by the editor:

The Paston **Letters**.

Alexander Pope: **Satires, Epistles, Poems**.

The **Diary** of an Edwardian Lady  (actually I bought that to give away).

Where the editor knows /knew the subject, and the material is mainly oral /aural history ‘**Reminiscences**’ may be suitable, or 'Conversations with...'